# Change mouse wheel scroll lines?

Tags: vb.net, scroll, scrollbar, mouseevent, mousewheel

I have a panel with autoscroll and I need to change the mouse scroll lines number

I will mean this:

(Mouse properties in spanish, sorry)

[image]

But I will change it in my program, for my panel, obvius, not in the SO!

PS: for example the Winamp media player have an option for that.

I can't find info anywhere, please help.

> UPDATE

My scrollbar is a panel with "AutoScroll" property

My event is this:

```
    Private Sub Panel1_MouseScroll(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Panel1.MouseWheel

    Panel1.Invalidate()

    End Sub
```

This is the content of my panel:

```
  ' Checkbox drawing
Public Sub updatecheckboxes()
    ' delete the old checkboxes
    Panel1.Controls.Clear()
    ' create the new checkboxes
    Dim filesystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim ThisDir = filesystem.GetFolder(My.Settings.folderpath)
    Dim i As Int32 = 0
    Dim pos As Int32 = 10
    For Each folder In ThisDir.Subfolders
        Array.Resize(mcheck, i + 1)
        mcheck(i) = New CheckBox
        With mcheck(i)
            .AutoSize = True
            .Location = New Point(10, pos)
            .Name = "CheckBox" & i + 1
            .Text = folder.Name
        End With
        Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(mcheck(i))
        AddHandler mcheck(i).CheckedChanged, AddressOf LlamadaCheckBox
        i += 1
        pos += 20
    Next

End Sub
```

[image]

I want to change the number of scrolled lines because of the distorted efefct inside the panel, If i use "one scoll-page" or "10 scrolls at time" like the imagen of Windows SO properties then I can fix it!

Comment: You want to change `Mouse Properties -> Wheel -> The following number of lines at a time` to any number from your program?

Comment: I have a panel, and when i use the mouse-wheel in my app then i want to scroll "X" lines, for example 20 lines down or up, thankyou for comment and for your answer

Comment: Right now it does not scroll at all, is that correct? (this is what I am experiencing, i.e. default Panel does not scroll on MouseWheel)

Comment: You are trying to mimic functionality of [CheckedListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.aspx). Please don't reinvent the wheel and use native components instead. You will have a lot less headache in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SendMessage` to scroll by any number of lines you want, regardless of what's in `SystemInformation.MouseWheelScrollLines`. [MouseWheel event does not occur for a Panel](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vblanguage/thread/a90d3574-afaa-4990-bade-6ddcb053c61f). So I tested this on a TextBox:

```
Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
               (ByVal handle As IntPtr, ByVal wMsg As Integer,
                ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As Integer) As Integer
```

Scroll one line up:

```
SendMessage(TextBox1.Handle, &HB6, 0, -1)
```

Scroll one line down:

```
SendMessage(TextBox1.Handle, &HB6, 0, 1)
```

The last parameter is a number of lines, sign indicates direction. Negative - up, positive - down.

You should be able to override/suppress mouse wheel handling and insert these two statements instead, depending on the sign of `delta` value being passed.

Comment: thanks, I've tried to send that messages with you example but I still scrolling 5 default lines... maybe i'm doing something wrong

Comment: @ElektroHacker: Could be that you did not cancel the original event. But please take `CheckedListBox` into consideration. It should solve most of your problems.

Comment: I can't make a checkedlistbox transparent and it don't have AutoScroll for adding a scrollbar (I don't have idea of how to add manually one), thankyou anyway

Comment: @ElektroHacker: To make it transparent, see [Transparent ListBox on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11359/Transparent-ListBox). CheckedListBox inherits from a ListBox, so the same technique should work. Scrollbars will appear automatically, if contents needs scrolling. Or set `ScrollAlwaysVisible = True` to show all the time.

Answer (score 2):

The `MouseEventArgs` object has a property `Delta` to determine the amount the mouse wheel was scrolled. Furthermore, there is `SystemInformation.MouseWheelScrollLines`. There is a current constant called `WHEEL_DELTA = 120` which reflects the delta that is added per mouse wheel tick.

So a good definition is:

```
Dim numberOfTextLinesToMove As Integer = CInt(e.Delta * SystemInformation.MouseWheelScrollLines / 120)
```

Source: [Control.MouseWheel Event on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousewheel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: sorry i'm beginner, i've tried to use it but i don't know how to do it, can you give me a example please?

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the MSDN Example for the [MouseWheel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousewheel.aspx) Event. They suggest something like this you can change the amount changed by replacing SystemInformation.MouseWheelScrollLines with the number of lines you want to scroll.

From Link:

```
Private Sub panel1_MouseWheel(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles panel1.MouseWheel
        ' Update the drawing based upon the mouse wheel scrolling. 
    Dim numberOfTextLinesToMove As Integer = CInt(e.Delta * SystemInformation.MouseWheelScrollLines / 120)
    Dim numberOfPixelsToMove As Integer = numberOfTextLinesToMove * fontSize

    If numberOfPixelsToMove <> 0 The
        Dim translateMatrix As New System.Drawing.Drawing2D.Matrix()
        translateMatrix.Translate(0, numberOfPixelsToMove)
        mousePath.Transform(translateMatrix)
    End If
    panel1.Invalidate()
End Sub
```

---

An additional example:

I turned of AutoScroll because it seems to want to at least give you a Minimum of the System Scroll Lines. I had to put some checks in to keep from continually scrolling pass the extents. Play with it and see if it works for you.

```
Private Sub panel1_MouseWheel(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Panel1.MouseWheel
    Dim numberOfTextLinesToMove As Integer = CInt(e.Delta * 20 / 120)
    Dim numberOfPixelsToMove As Integer = numberOfTextLinesToMove * mcheck(0).Font.Size

    If numberOfPixelsToMove <> 0 Then
        If (numberOfPixelsToMove > 0) Then
            If (mcheck(0).Top >= 0) Then Exit Sub
        Else
            If (mcheck(mcheck.Length - 1).Top) <= Panel1.Height Then Exit Sub
        End If

        TranslateCheckboxes(numberOfPixelsToMove)
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Panel1.Invalidate()
End Sub

Private Sub TranslateCheckboxes(pixels As Integer)
    For x = 0 To mcheck.Length - 1
        mcheck(x).Top += pixels
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: `fontSize` and `mousePath` are undeclared?

Comment: @LarsTech: yeah, I know - just trying to match the referenced article with the question to reproduce in an isolated project (without drawing mouse path) - no luck so far.

Comment: sorry i'm beginner, i've tried to use it but i don't know how to do it. i've defined fontsize and mousepath like in the example of msdn, i've changed the integer values but...nothing

Comment: @electrohacker try posting the contents of your panel what you are trying to scroll, their example was a mouse drawing example. Unfortunately I will not be back by a computer for a few hours

Comment: @Mark Gall thankyou for your time, i've updated my question adding more info